# find last instance of a div.class, then remove another class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

wondering if it's possible to write a script that would do the following:

find the last instance of a div of a particular class. It would then remove from that div, a different class  that the div is also given.

to see what i mean here is a screen-snap of the site. the actual site is not available for viewing.

http://www.tomcarden.net/grid.html

the last cell (div) needs to have the class of '.grid' removed so that it can
then extend the length of it's containing div. thus the gray border would extend and the last cell would look much better,

extreme thanks for help on this!,

Answer (score 5):

Not too hard:

```
$('div.class:last').removeClass('otherClass')
```

But apparently using this code:

```
$('div.class').filter(':last').removeClass('otherClass')
```

Is much faster because `:last` isn't implemented using the native DOM, so the tree is traversed using jQuery's (slower) code.

Use the second block. The first block is only easier to read.

---

Ever thought about accepting your answers? If you don't provide feedback, how will anyone ever know what solution was bogus and what solution helped you?

Comment: +1 though jQuery recommends using `filter(":last")` on the matched set. See http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/

Answer (score 1):

```
$("div.classA").last().removeClass("classB");
```

Comment: I'd replace `first()` with `last()`.

Comment: oops, was rushing to beat you haha